# Can I download or upload file using CURL for file://///my_windows/test (non-http link)

Tags: windows, curl, http

I have a windows machine(Server 2012). I have a shared location in it restricted to my user id(\\my_windows\test). I have few files inside test folder. I want to upload or download files to this location using curl. Is this possible?

Whatever examples I saw till now has https or https as the url for Curl. I am able to open this network location in Mozilla with 'file://///my_windows/test'. I want to curl to this location. How do I do it or is there anyway that I can make this location to open with http url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with curl, as it doesn't support smb or URI.  Do you specifically need to use curl? Can you curl the machines IP (eg `http://1.2.3.4/remote/share`?

If it were my machine I would set it up as a samba share or by ftp.

Here is the man pages for curl: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Nelson for the response. I am not able to open it via http://1.2.3.4/remote/share. But I yesterday found a link which can make a windows share location to open with either FTP or HTTP/HTTPS.

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows

May be this will help me once I am able to open it via http. Will check and update. Thanks again!

Comment: @Raji I have a similar job that am trying to resolve and I have the same question as yours. How did you solve this are you able to upload files using `curl` `FILE`. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An old thread, but I found my way here...

This can be done with curl.

A download can be done like this:

`curl -o /path/to/output.file smb://my_windows/test/input.file -u username:passwd`

It's important to note that curl uses DNS to resolve `my_windows`, rather than NETBIOS, so you may need to use a local DNS resolver or add the name to your hosts file.  It is often easier to use the IP address.

Uploads are similar:

`curl -T /path/to/input.file smb://my_windows/test/output.file -u username:passwd`